# Can i make my classname variable in sass?

Tags: sass

Is it possible to make a classname variable in sass. If so how can i do the following:

```
$colorlist();

$blue:    #007bff;
$yellow:  #99s9e0;
$red:  #f4i304;

$colorlist: map-merge((
 "blue":   $blue,
 "yellow":  $yellow,
 "red":     $red,
)
$colorlist
);
```

now i want to write in HTML class:"bg-blue" bg is a class that gives the element 
a background color defined by the color after the '-' sign.

currently i have this:

```
$red:  #900;
$colorlist();
$colorlist: map-merge(
                (
                       "color1": $red,
                ),
                $colorlist
);


.bg-#{$colorlist} {
  background-color: $colorlist;
}
```

with suggestion of ReSedano

```
$red:  #900;
$colorlist();
$color();
$colorlist: map-merge(
                (
                       "color1": $red,
                ),
                $colorlist
);


.backg-#{$color} {
  background-color: map_get($colorlist,$color);
}
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for are mixins.

Comment: yeah but i want to write my own mixin

Comment: Try to use `map-get()` function => http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_get-instance_method

Comment: thank you for you suggestion. But still nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$red:  #900;
$colorlist:();
$color:();
$colorlist: map-merge(
   (
      red: $red,
    ),
  $colorlist
);

@mixin background($color){
  .backg-#{$color} {
    background-color: map-get($colorlist,$color);
  }
}


@include background(red);
```

Your output will be this:

```
.backg-red {
  background-color: #900;
}
```